# SyntaxError: missing before statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this console error "SyntaxError: missing  before statement" everytime I add the following code (with a double space between "missing" and "before", no ";". | On Codecademy classroom | The entire code works when I erase it) :

```
var headphones() {
    headphonesQuest = confirm('Voulez-vous mettre vos écouteurs pour écouter de la musique durant votre périple ?');
    if (headphonesQuest) {
        alert('Zut ! Plus de batterie...');
    }
};
```

This is the full Javascript :

```
var utilisateur = prompt('Vous comptiez vous rendre à la bibliotèque en/à :\n\n - vélo\n - pied\n - autobus\n - métro\n - taxi').toLowerCase();
var headphonesQuest = false;
var headphones() {
    headphonesQuest = confirm('Voulez-vous mettre vos écouteurs pour écouter de la musique durant votre périple ?');
    if (headphonesQuest) {
        alert('Zut ! Plus de batterie...');
    }
};


switch(utilisateur) {
  case 'velo':
      alert('Vous avez choisis de prendre le vélo pour votre quête.');
      headphones();
    break;
  case 'pied':
      alert('Vous avez choisis d\'y aller à pied pour votre quête.');
      headphones();
    break;
  case 'autobus':
      alert('Vous avez choisis de prendre l\'autobus pour votre quête.');
      headphones();
    break;
  case 'metro':
      alert('Vous avez choisis de prendre le métro pour votre quête.');
      headphones();
    break;
  case 'taxi':
      alert('Vous avez choisis de prendre le taxi pour votre quête.');
      headphones();
    break;
  default:
      alert('Vous n\'avez pas entré de choix valide pour votre quête.');
}
```

Comment: `var headphones() {` is invalid syntax. Did you want to use the `function` keyword?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused

Here is a function expression:

```
var headphones = function () {
    headphonesQuest = confirm('Voulez-vous mettre vos écouteurs pour écouter de la musique durant votre périple ?');
    if (headphonesQuest) {
        alert('Zut ! Plus de batterie...');
    }
};
```

And here is a function declaration:

```
function headphones() {
    headphonesQuest = confirm('Voulez-vous mettre vos écouteurs pour écouter de la musique durant votre périple ?');
    if (headphonesQuest) {
        alert('Zut ! Plus de batterie...');
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a statement only if used improperly (such as [in a block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Conditionally_created_functions)), it should be a declaration - that's what everybody else calls it. I'll fix Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the line bellow

```
var headphones() {
```

I think it should be

```
var headphones = function() {
```

Or

```
function headphones(){
```